# Is it safe to manually install a new kernel for Debian and other distributions?

Tags: debian, kernel, gcc

Is it generally safe to manually compile and install a new kernel from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/) using:

```
make -j 8
make install 
make modules_install
```

or might the distribution, e.g. Debian, break, because it assumes that it manages kernel upgrades through `apt`?

Intuitively, everything should continue to work, since the kernel preserves a stable syscall API, and the drivers are compatible with earlier versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it’s safe; Debian doesn’t require a packaged kernel, and as you say the kernel is backwards-compatible. You only need to make sure your kernel configuration is functional.

However, you can build a kernel package [from the upstream kernel source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.14/source/scripts/Makefile.package#L147), and install the resulting packages instead. Run this in the kernel source tree, instead of `make install modules_install`:

```
make deb-pkg
```

See also [the Debian kernel handbook](https://kernel-team.pages.debian.net/kernel-handbook/ch-common-tasks.html) which explains how to build kernel packages in a variety of scenarios.

Comment: Thanks. I see `make deb-pkg` works although a quick inspection of the Makefile doesn't reveral any `deb-pkg` target, but I found it in `./scripts/Makefile.package`. When Debian installs a new kernel is that through `apt` or how is it managed?

Comment: I added a link to the Makefile while you were looking ;-). `make help` from the root of the source tree summarises all the available targets. Debian kernels are managed using `apt`, see [the `linux` packages](https://tracker.debian.org/linux) (`linux-image-...`).

Comment: I wish there was a generic `help` target that would list all available targets in a Makefile. `make help` only seems to work for Makefiles that have implemented that target as a helper